# Reloading Activity in the Present Tab

Tags: android, tabactivity

I have noticed that if I try clicking on the present tab to go back to the first screen of that particular activity, the action does not happen at all. While many answers suggest including the addFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP), it doesn't happen at all.

Let's say that the current tab is a search Activity. This has been defined in the MainActivity file:

```
final Intent searchIntent = new Intent().setClass(this, SearchActivity.class);
     searchIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
TabSpec tabSearch = tabHost.newTabSpec(AppConstants.TAG_SEARCH).setIndicator("",resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_search_off_btn)).setContent(searchIntent);
```

The navigation path would be from SearchActivity -> SearchByBankFragment -> CardListFragment -> CategoryListFragment ->.

What happens is that I can switch different tabs without a hitch. But going back to the main level in the same tab is not happening.

Say I am under CardListFragment and I decide to go back to the main level of SearchActivity, I would definitely click the tab button above. But what I am unsure is that whether if I have omitted.

Just to see whether it's got to do with onResume,I have overriden the onResume method and added the invalidate command or something.

Have I missed out something in either at the fragment level or at the main activity itself?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you just need to remove all of the Fragments that have been piled onto the backstack.  Using popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE) should do the trick.  Call that when the user hit's that top most tab.

Comment: I think at this point of time, TabHost doesn't have the function to handle events if the currentTab is the same as the tab Clicked. Maybe as some said that another sub class of the TabHost has to be created to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

> "Sounds like you just need to remove all of the Fragments that have
>   been piled onto the backstack. Using popBackStack(null,
>   FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE) should do the trick. Call
>   that when the user hit's that top most tab."

I surmise that you are referring to implementing that popStackBack in each of the fragments under that activity is it not? I tried doing a onTabChanged, unfortunately it is not working really.

Here's some of the essential lines in the code of the SearchBankFragment I am testing (it's in OnCreateView):

```
final Activity activity = SearchActivity.activity //parent Activity;
final TabHost tabHost = (TabHost) activity.getParent().findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

I just tried putting a onTabChanged event, which I don't think it works:

```
tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, new SearchMainFragment());
            ft.remove(SearchBankFragment.this);
            fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            ft.commit();

        }
    });
```

Note: Navigation is like: SearchActivity -> SearchMainFragment -> SearchBankFragment -> CardListFragment -> CategoryListFragment -> OfferListFragment -> OfferActivity